# Cursor barely visible when editing mesh

Tags: 3d-view

I wonder if there's any way to change the cursor's appearance or size. I guess not, I couldn't find anything (there used to be a couple of checks in Preferences but not since 2.8 I think), but just in case, I'll leave this here.

Thanks,

EDIT: Yes, I especially meant the crosshair cursor, and I'm on Linux (adding this new information here according to the guidelines because of the first answer I got, thanks anyway).

Comment: Hello :). Which cursor do you mean? The crosshair cursor can be changed in your system (Win/MacOS) settings, not in Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I was blind before, or if this was added with the latest update I got (2.82.7), but now on Preferences->Display there is the "Large Cursors" checkbox (and there's also the Line Thick picker). So problem solved.