# How do I enlarge the mouse pointer in Blender 2.83?

Tags: interface, customization

The cross-hair pointer in Edit mode is too small for easy location. I believe earlier versions of Blender had a 'Large Cursor' option in the Display section of Preferences. Can someone tell me whether such a feature still exists, and if so where to find it.

Comment: you could use the circle select by pressing C and then adjust the circle's size.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it's not really selection that's the problem. It's the visibility of the tiny cross-hair cursor when using any of the other tools in Edit mode.

Comment: I've found a (very) partial workaround: if you press B, the cross-hairs extend across the 3D window. But I would still very much prefer a larger cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of your cursor in Windows or whatever OS you use. It will increase your cross hairs size

Comment: See the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181049/cursor-barely-visible-when-editing-mesh Note that the option is at Edit > Preferences > **Interface** > Display. (Interface was left out of the answer.)